# updateblob fails in Powerbuilder

Tags: blob, powerbuilder

In Powerbuilder I am trying to update a table (Oracle) with blob but get sqlerror, "Database statement must refer to blob variable".  My declaration and updateblob statements are as follows:

```
blob lblob_newxml
long llong_subid

UPDATEBLOB RP_XML_FORMS SET XML_DOC = :lblob_newxml
WHERE SUBMISSION_ID = :llong_subid
USING SQLCA;
```

Does anybody know why it is happening and or how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get more information on this problem and the possible causes, I'd run with one of the database traces turned on. (You can check out database trace options in the [Connecting to Your Database manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37776.1250/html/connpb/title.htm); link may not be appropriate for your PB version, which you haven't mentioned yet.) This may or may not tell you more, but it tracks everything between the app and when the PB drivers pass the commands "over the wall" to the database's driver.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

"The PowerBuilder VM can get the SQL syntax for the following types of errors, and passes it to the Transaction object’s DBError event for the following types of errors: ..." (see [this page](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/CAIECBBATO.htm)).

If your lblob_newxml is null then use this update statement instead:

```
UPDATE RP_XML_FORMS SET XML_DOC = NULL
WHERE SUBMISSION_ID = :llong_subid
USING SQLCA;
```